# How to obtain active genres in activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am using Rails 3 and postgresql. I have the following genres: rock, ambience, alternative, house.

I also have two users registered. One has **rock** and the other **house**, as their genres. I need to return rock and house genre objects.

I found two ways to do this. One is using group:

```
Genre.group('genres.id, genres.name, genres.cached_slug, genres.created_at, genres.updated_at').joins(:user).all
```

And the other using DISTINCT:

```
Genre.select('DISTINCT(genres.name), genres.cached_slug').joins(:user)
```

Both return the same desired results. But which one is better performance wise? Using group() looks messy since I have to indicate all the fields in the Genre table otherwise I'll get errors as such:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "genres.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
: SELECT genres.id FROM "genres" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."genre_id" = "genres"."id" GROUP BY genres.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` usually generate the same query plan, so performance should be the same across both query constructs.

Since you're not using any aggregate functions, you should use the one that makes the most sense in your situation, which I believe is this one:

```
Genre.select('DISTINCT(genres.name), genres.cached_slug').joins(:user)
```

This will be more clear when trying to read your code later and remember what you did here and, as you pointed out, is much less messy.

**Update**

It depends on the version of Postgresql you are using.  Using versions < 8.4, `GROUP BY` is faster. With version 8.4 and later, they are the same.

Comment: Cleaned it up more with: Genre.select('DISTINCT(genres.name), genres.*').joins(:user)